# ¿Cómo mostrar el nombre del usuario logueado a mi aplicación web?

Tags: jsf, hibernate, glassfish

Como puedo mostrar el nombre del usuario que se logea?

Con esto puedo mostrar el user y lo que quiero es mostrar el nombre, hay alguna forma de hacerlo ?
[image: Estoy usando esto]

Answer (score 1):

Tiene dos opciones.

1. Buscar a la entidad (usuario) por su `getRemoteUser()` que viene a ser el `id` cada vez que requiera (no tiene mucho sentido ...).
2. Normalmente si el usuario ingresa al sitio, lo primero que se hace es crear una sesión para éste no ?

Por qué no crear un managed bean que se encargue de ingresar éste usuario a la sesión ? Que retenga la información del usuario logeado, con eso tiene accesso a éste de forma inmediata siempre y cuando la sesión siga activa.

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
fc.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("usuario", usuario);
```

Donde `usuario` proviene de una búsqueda de un servicio `EJB`.

E.G.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class InfoUsuario implements Serializable{

   private EntidadUsuario user;

   @EJB
   private ServicioUsuario userService;

   public EntidadUsuario getUser(){
       if(user == null){
         Principal principal = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();

         user = userService.findById(principal.getName());
       }

      return user;
   }
}
```

De esta forma el usuario en sesión tiene toda su información y puede ser accessible desde el Facelet a través de EL así:

```
#{infoUsuario.user.nombre}
```

Comment: Pero si ya se maneja por el realm, ¿para qué almacenarlo en un nuevo lugar?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza El ream guarda todo ? id,nombre,apellido,dirección,etc. ? de ser así podrías dar una respuesta para yo también aprender ?

Comment: No lo creo, es solo para seguridad, manejo de roles y usuarios.

Comment: Si eso pienso yo, por eso si el nombre y apellido no son parete del usuario pues hay que buscarlos no ?

Answer (score -1):

Normalmente las sesiones se almacenan en los beans con sus respectivos Scopes con @SessionScoped 
debería bastar para almacenar toda la información que se designe dentro de la clase durante toda la sesión.

Ahora,normalmente la información de los usuarios se guarda en la base de datos, lo que yo haría es que al momento de hacer el login guardar el usuario en un bean con @SessionScoped que tenga declarado el objeto Usuario.

```
package mx.tuProyecto.controllers;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import mx.tuProyecto.entities.Notification;
import mx.tuProyecto.entities.User;
import mx.materiam.sessions.UserManager;


@SessionScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    UserManager userManager;
    User user;
    String email;
    String password;

    public Bean(){
    user = new User();
    }

    public void login() {
      try {
        HttpServletRequest r = (HttpServletRequest)                                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        setDestination(r.getHeader("referer") + "?faces-   redirect=true");
        try {
            r.login(email, password);
            user = userManager.getUserByEmail(email));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                            e.getMessage(), null));
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/25826)

Comment: revisores: las revisiones no son para reportar imprecisiones técnicas. Esta respuesta [se ve bien].

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster esto no es un comentario, es una respuesta y necesita un poco más de apoyo para convertirse en una respuesta de mayor calidad.

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta :)